# Проблемы с датой и временем

Tags: html, datetime

Всем привет, как мне кажется вопрос достаточно глуповатый, просто я не сильно разбираюсь в этом.
Такое дело. В Форме есть два поля с датой и временем. При активации submit , выводится такое оповещение.
[image: Алерт]

```html
<form th:action="@{/app/schedule/save}" th:method="post">
<input  type="hidden" id="scheduleId" th:name="id">

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Дата начала</th>
        <th scope="col">Понедельник</th>
        <th scope="col">Вторник</th>
        <th scope="col">Среда</th>
        <th scope="col">Четверг</th>
        <th scope="col">Пятница</th>
        <th scope="col">Суббота</th>
        <th scope="col">Воскресенье</th>
        <th scope="col">Дата окончания</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startDate" th:name="startDateTime"></th>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="monday" th:name="isMonday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="tuesday" th:name="isTuesday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="wednesday" th:name="isWednesday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="thursday" th:name="isThursday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="friday" th:name="isFriday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="saturday" th:name="isSaturday"></td>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="sunday" th:name="isSunday"></td>
        <th scope="row"><input type="datetime-local"  class="form-control" id="endDate" th:name="endDateTime"></th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
```

Comment: Добавьте `step="1"` чтобы разрешить секунды